# What is a good reference for the formal mathematical definition of algorithm and heuristic?

Tags: logic, algorithms

I am looking for a good reference for the definitions of algorithm and heuristics.

According to [Alg1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2005293/360752) and 
[Alg2](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/66754/71224) the formal definition 
uses Turing machines. I think there are equivalent methods, see 
[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine_equivalents) or 
J. Flum, Einführung in die mathematische Logik
Is there anything better?

On the other hand, I could not find anything about a formal definition of heuristics.
Does a precise mathematical definition for heuristics exist?

I am looking for a broadly supported reference.
(I hope, something like "Feynman Lectures" or the famous "1905 Einstein" papers exist ;-)).

**Comments / questions to the answer @Carl Mummert**:
The [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmus) states "...using Turing machnines, we can provide 
the following formal definition [of algorithm]:
A calculation instruction for solving a problem is an algorithm if and only if there exists an equivalent Turing machine
for this calculation instruction and given any input where a solution to the input exists, this Turing machine halts.
**What is wrong with that definition?**

Comment: For algorithm, maybe [Feynman Lectures On Computation](https://books.google.it/books?id=x9ZiDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Regarding heuristic, it is difficult... maybe Polya's [How to solve it](https://books.google.it/books?id=X3xsgXjTGgoC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Please don't link to commercial sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no single mathematical definition of an "algorithm". There is a well accepted definition of a *computable function* - the class of computable functions can be defined in terms of Turing machines, register machines, and many other models of computation.

However, this does not answer the problem of defining an "algorithm", because every computable function has many different programs to compute it, and it is not clear how to tell whether two programs use the same algorithm or use different algorithms.

This is also why "program" or "Turing machine" cannot be used as a definition of an algorithm. A key aspect of the term "algorithm" is that the same algorithm can be turned into many different programs.

So the definition of "computable function" is too coarse to capture the meaning of "algorithm", while the definition of "program" is too fine.

In computability theory and computer science, "algorithm" is used only as an informal term, or to refer to a specific set of instructions. In other words, we know particular algorithms, such as Djiktra's algorithm, but we don't have a definition of "algorithm" in general.

For a partial list of attempts to define "algorithm", see [algorithm characterizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm_characterizations) on Wikipedia.  At least 15 different attempts are described there.

Comment: Another way to understand why it's hard to define "algorithm" is to look to Quine's slogan "no entity without identity". The slogan means, in this case, that any precise formal definition of an algorithm would need to provide a concrete way of telling whether two algorithms are the same algorithm or are genuinely different algorithms. There is no generally accepted criterion of that sort, apart from ones that are too coarse or too fine. If we accept Quine's slogan, solving the problem of precisely defining an "algorithm" also requires solving the problem of when two algorithms are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I have enough to read :-) is there a book you would recommend? It seems your are talking about things which became basic knowledge...

Comment: Sorry, but I think I really miss a crucial point - see my edit to the question. Any hint is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A heuristic is usually a "trick" used in an algorithm to improve some of its performance (usually the expected time complexity), and is of the same nature as an algorithm. In this sense, it follows the same formalization.

On the other hand, a heuristic needn't have a rigorous justification, it can be purely intuitive. In this sense, there is nothing you can formalize.

Comment: Is there any reference to a book or an article?

Comment: @Christoph: never seen that. There is no "theory" of heuristics.